# Google maps do not have border radius

Tags: css, google-maps, google-chrome

when we use google maps to display maps can not make round edges

Issue only on chrome

HTML

```
<div id="mapframe">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mapframe {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #555;

}

#map {
    width: 290px;
    height: 320px;
    border-radius: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zsVjG/

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368627/in-webkit-browsers-v3-google-maps-do-not-respect-containers-border-radius-any

Answer (score 2):

Correct. Border radius CSS styling for an object containing a Google Map v3 is not rendered in Chrome. Other browsers, such as FireFox and Opera, respect the settings. Note that Chrome did not have this issue with Google Maps v2, but since the plug will be pulled on that in May, the point is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Give iframe parent to `display:flex;`

and then give iframe to `border-radius:15px;`

It's work for me

Comment: display flex was not an option on 2013 but thank you ahah