# Border Radius on iPad and iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm having a problem with border-radius on iPhone and iPad. I'm trying to generate a round googlemap, which is working fine in every browser and on every system except ios.
What I've done so far is, I've got a map-canvas

```
<div class="col-sm-4"><div id="map_canvas"></div></div>
```

and my css

```
#map_canvas {
    height:474px;
    width:474px;
    border-radius:237px;
    margin-bottom:73px;
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
```

after this wasn't working, i tried to add more border-radius:

```
.gm-style {
    height:474px;
    width:474px;
    border-radius:237px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
#map_canvas .gm-style > div {
    border-radius:237px;
}
```

but still no success. Here's a live example:
http://kristinwalzer.at/website/kontakt.php

Anyone knows this problem? And a solution perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Add one more `div` for round box and add properties to that round box

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="roundBox">
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
   </div>
</div>


.roundBox{
    height:474px;
    width:474px;
    border-radius:237px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 999; 
}

#map_canvas {
    height:474px;
    width:474px;
    display: block;
    border-radius:237px;
}
```

Comment: You need to add `border-radius:237px;` to `#map_canvas` also

Comment: I can see the circle, but in the moment the map is loaded, the border-radius is gone. A second `overflow:hidden` isn't helping either.

Comment: You need to add `border-radius:237px;` to both `.roundBox` and `#map_canvas`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57842/discussion-between-amol-and-andi).

Comment: at least not at my iphone :(

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [In webkit browsers, v3 google maps do not respect container's border-radius. Anyone have a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368627/in-webkit-browsers-v3-google-maps-do-not-respect-containers-border-radius-any#answer-17755609)

All fiddles in this post won't work on safari (windows and ios).
But even if they said in that question that it is solved, it is not. Looks like a Googlemap V3 Bug.